# Integrating Adsense with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, adsense

Alright, so I don't know what's going on. 
I've been trying to add Adsense to my site for the past three hours now, and it just doesn't work.

The site in discussion is www.salty.in (it's a replica of Google, but in a smart way, it's a direct Reddit replica, actually. It's used to browse Reddit, and it is simply said, a brilliant idea.

The Github is public, but I'll post my updated code. Keep in mind, I took over this project from a friend of mine.

This copy of the script is fully non-commented, so sorry about that.
http://hastebin.com/ujagutiqiy.php

Beginning at line 108, I've added the JavaScript for Adsense. This is the only place where it DOESN'T crash when I use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your adsense code inside `<body> //adsenseCode </body>` tag.

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-4339410594143631"
         data-ad-slot="5222326700"
         data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
```

Below is the script file that supports Adsense
`<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`

You can place this with either your site's scripts ( i.e. outside `body` ) or inside `body`

Comment: I have integrated it on line 103, would this work? http://hastebin.com/ugafakaniz.php

Comment: Having 2 body tag is bad practice. remove from line 103, and paste it to line 134... and remove those body tags you added on 103.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend just to move

```
<!-- 123 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-4339410594143631"
     data-ad-slot="5222326700"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

these lines from line 108 to line 193 before closing of body tag